# How to generate a keystore file for a Jetty server from PEM file?

Tags: java, encryption, ssl

I got a certificate.pem file from the CA, that have structure like below:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
encrypted text of the public key
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

From this, we need to generate the keystore file that could be read by the Jetty server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use any of the Cygwin, Linux, Solaris machine, 
   OpenSSL:

```
pkcs12 -export -inkey ls09953_server.key -in certiface.pem -out certiface.pkcs12
```

- ls09953_server.key -> is the private key file that was used to generate the csr and send to CA.
- certiface.pem -> is the .pem file send by your CA.

2. From the command prompt where your Java is located, such as `c:/program files/java/jdk1.6.x.x/bin/` (run as administrator) generate a keystore and provide a password. Other details can be left; just press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias endeca -keystore certiface.ks
```

3. Now delete extra info from the keystore:

```
keytool -delete -alias endeca -keystore certiface.ks
```

4. You have `.pks12` file (from step 1) and the blank keystore (from step 3). Now, import the `pkcs12` file into this keystore:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certiface.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore certiface.ks
```

5. Place this in your certificate directory and use it like a regular one.

Answer (score -1):

The Tomcat doc has a pretty good tutorial on this topic:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration

basicly:
read the chapter
"Prepare the Certificate Keystore" and "Importing the Certificate"

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from your reference link.  Your answer alone, should be able to answer the question, it currently does not.

Comment: basicly, the whole link is a how-to-tutorial, so you just need... well, everything from the link - so I didn't see the point of quoting

Comment: Let me clear, I don't need to read the link, I already know how to do it.  However, everyone else might need assistance, so my comment is for those people.  You now know how to fix your answer.